# NewtonSoft JSON Deserialization: System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

The JSON deserialization is failing with the exception System.StackOverflowException.

I'm trying the deserialize the following entity. Need help, why this is causing the issue.

```
var workingJSONString = "{\"FBTOrLeaseYear\":{\"DateFrom\":\"2019-03-02T00:00:00\",\"DateTo\":\"2020-03-01T00:00:00\"},\"Registration\":\"155SQN\",\"NovatedLeaseFortnightBenefitGroups\":[],\"NovatedLeaseAnnualBenefitGroups\":[]}";

var exceptionJSONString = "{\"FBTOrLeaseYear\":{\"DateFrom\":\"2019-03-02T00:00:00\",\"DateTo\":\"2020-03-01T00:00:00\"},\"Registration\":\"155SQN\",\"NovatedLeaseFortnightBenefitGroups\":[{\"BenefitGroupID\":1,\"BenefitGroupName\":\"Fuel\",\"TotalAnnualBudgetAmount\":4992.0000,\"TotalFortnightBudgetAmount\":192.0000,\"TotalSpentToDate\":3327.43,\"TotalFortnightSpent\":141.59276595744680851063829788,\"TotalProjAnnualAmount\":3681.4119148936170212765957447,\"TotalVariationAmount\":1310.5880851063829787234042553,\"AverageSpentPercentage\":14.645499465811966666666666667,\"NovatedLeaseBudgetSpentDataForBenefits\":[]}],\"NovatedLeaseAnnualBenefitGroups\":[]}";

Test.Entities.NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear novatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYearResponse = new Test.Entities.NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear();

novatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYearResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test.Entities.NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear>(exceptionJSONString); // Exception is thrown here
```

**Entities:**

On deserialization of the "Test.Entities.NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear" entity,

I'm getting an exception **"System.StackOverflowException"**. Can one please help me why the deserizarion is failing for this JSON.

```
public class NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear
{
    public FBTOrLeaseYear FBTOrLeaseYear { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public List<NovatedLeaseBenefitGroup> NovatedLeaseFortnightBenefitGroups { get; set; }
    public List<NovatedLeaseBenefitGroup> NovatedLeaseAnnualBenefitGroups { get; set; }
}

 public class NovatedLeaseBenefitGroup
{
    public int BenefitGroupID { get; set; }
    public string BenefitGroupName { get; set; }
    public double TotalAnnualBudgetAmount { get; set; }
    public double TotalFortnightBudgetAmount { get; set; }
    public double TotalSpentToDate { get; set; }
    public double TotalFortnightSpent { get; set; }
    public double TotalProjAnnualAmount { get; set; }
    public double TotalVariationAmount { get; set; }
    public double AverageSpentPercentage { get; set; }
    public List<NovatedLeaseBudgetSpentDataForBenefit> NovatedLeaseBudgetSpentDataForBenefits { get; set; }
}

public class NovatedLeaseBudgetSpentDataForBenefit
{
    public int BenefitId { get; set; }
    public string BenefitName { get; set; }
    public double AnnualBudgetAmount { get; set; }
    public double FortnightBudgetAmount { get; set; }
    public double SpentToDate { get; set; }
    public double FortnightSpent { get; set; }
    public double ProjAnnualAmount { get; set; }
    public double VariationAmount { get; set; }
    public double SpentPercentage { get; set; }
}

public class FBTOrLeaseYear
{
    public string DateFrom { get; set; }
    public string DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share structure of FBTOrLeaseYear

Comment: this is probably a recursion issue. Probably something in your json is recursively defined.

Comment: @AnuViswan Updated FBTOrLeaseYear. Please check

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, didn't get `System.StackOverflowException`

Comment: @EnricoMassone If i add the data to the list for the property "NovatedLeaseFortnightBenefitGroups" or "NovatedLeaseAnnualBenefitGroups" to the entity "NovatedLeaseBenefitsBudgetSpentFBTYear" then the deserialization is failing. Not able to notice any recursive data here. Please let me know if you notice any pattern

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm using .Net framework v4.6 and NewtonSoft v12.0.3

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue too. Your example works fine.

Comment: @AryanM I've checked with the same version of Newtonsoft on .NET Core 3 and .NET 4.7. Did you use any specific serialization settings or set `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` somewhere?

Comment: These entities are referred from a DLL reference. Ill see if there are any issues with the mapping of these properties. Thank you guys

Comment: Notice that with newtonsoft json there is the possibility to use the so called global settings as documented here (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm). Be sure that nowhere in your project you are using global settings like these. Maybe some of them could break the example that you posted. Again, with the default settings of newtonsoft json I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: A possible cause of your issue is the usage of this setting https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm

Comment: The issue is only coming when i use the referenced object. The referenced object class and property names are exactly the same. Whenever i use the external DLL referenced object i get the exception. Not sure why though :( The response is coming of type DLL referenced object, so need to get this working with the referenced object.